# Cambiar color de fondo en Matplotlib

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, color

estoy generando unos gráficos en una aplicación de escritorio realizada con Tkinter. El problema que tengo es que me genera unos gráficos muy simples, con el fondo blanco, y me esta costando mucho encontrar información en Internet sobre como puedo jugar con el color de fondo, la fuente del titulo, agregar alguna descripción si es posible. A ver si alguien puede ayudarme a cambiar el color de fondo aunque sea. Un saludo, y gracias.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Application(ttk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, main_window):
       super().__init__(main_window)
    main_window.geometry("600x600")

    plt.figure('3')  # Crea una ventana titulada '3'
    self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    self.ax.plot(np.random.randn(150), np.random.randn(150), 'o')
    self.ax.set_title('Ejemplo grafico de puntos')

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=main_window)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main_window = tk.Tk()
   app = Application(main_window)
   app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

[La doc de tkinter](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)

Por lo que veo, parece que creas un `Canvas`.

En la documentación, hay un apartado de "atributos estándar"

https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/std-attrs.html

En él te dicen:

> Cada widget tiene una serie de opciones que afectan a su comportamiento o su apariencia, como fuentes, colores, tamaños de texto, etiquetas...
>
> Puedes especificar las opciones deseadas, cuando llamas al constructor del widget, especificando las propiedades que quieres como argumentos: `text='PANIC!' or height=20.`

Una de esas opciones, son [los colores](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/colors.html)

Dice claramente, que tienes que utlizar códigos de color (`#000` por ejemplo)

Entonces, en tu caso, si estás creando un canvas, deberías ir a [la documentación del Canvas](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) Y en ella se ve que la primera opción, es la del background:

Así, que mirando cómo se utiliza el constructor, debe de ser:

```
 w = tk.Canvas(parent, option=value, ...)
```

Por tanto, donde haces:

```
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=main_window)
```

Deberías hacer

```
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=main_window, bg='#000')
```

**EDIT - Coloreando MathPlotLib embebido**

Al producirse el error que comenta el usuario, parece que se trata de mathplotlib embebido.

Es por tanto, que se deben cambiar los colores del canvas de mathplotlib, incluyendo la orden:

```
self.ax.set_facecolor('tab:red')
```

Donde el color, estará entre los [colores de MathPlotLib](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html?highlight=color#module-matplotlib.colors)

**EDIT**

> El usuario comenta que solo se cambia el color del MathPlot. PAra
>   cambiar el canvas de atrás, llamaremos por tanto al config del main window, que es donde parece haberse "anidado" el canvas

```
 main_window.config(bg='#000')
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, gracias por la respuesta pero ya intente cambiar el fondo del canvas como tu dices pero me tira el siguiente error: 

self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=main_window, bg='#000')

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bg'

Esto no significa que el argumento bg no existe?

Comment: Me da la sensacion que relamente es una parte de mathplotlib, y por tanto no funcona igual, 

Te hago un edit a ver si así si que funciona

Comment: Con la instrucción que me has puesto: self.ax.set_facecolor('tab:red')

He conseguido cambiar el fondo del gráfico en si, pero se sigue viendo el fondo del canvas blanco y no se como cambiarlo.

Comment: self.canvas.config(bg='#000')

Comment: uno es el canvas de tkinter y el otro de mathplotlib por lo visto

Comment: No me funciona, me sigue tirando el error 'AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'config''

Comment: me sigue tirando el error 'AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'config' <-- hasta ahora no creo que te hubiera dicho eso!!! ;) si acaso , "ahora" te dará ese error -. El tema, que el canvas parece estar montado sobre el FRAME. El canvas pertenece entonces al MathPlot, y el frame a tkinter..... eso es lo que parece pues

Comment: El tema, es que tú le pasass un FRAME. `ttk.Frame`  y parece que lo conviertes en el main_window o algo asi... 

Puede que sea un main_window.config(bg='#000')

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar lo siguiente:

self.fig.patch.set_facecolor('red')

[image: Ejemplo]